# Upgrade to PHP 5.3.23 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, php5

I want to use Zend Framework 2. I have installed the ZendSkeleton Application. When I try to install Framework, I get the following error:

```
#> php composer.phar install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
    - zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
```

So I want to install PHP 5.3.23 on Ubuntu 12.04. Via apt-get nothing happens, so I added a repository.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

To be sure I restarted. Still I have PHP 5.3.10.

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr  4 2014 01:30:04) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

How can I upgrade to 5.3.23 or higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.3.10 is the latest version the third party PPA provides. If you want the latest PHP 5.3, you need to [download it from php.net](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) and compile it from source.

I would however recommend you use at least PHP 5.4 since 5.3 is only supported until July 2014. Or, if you can afford it, use 5.5 right away.